# threads modifying the same file

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads

Im trying to make n threads modify a file. I have indexes for every thread but I thougth that with those indexes I could make the fseek and fputc. it is giving me segmentation fault. is there a way of implementing this without using mutex?

Thread1

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    fseek(archE, i, SEEK_SET)
    fputc('*', archE)
}
```

Thread2

```
for (i=5; i<10; i++) {
    fseek(archE, i, SEEK_SET)
    fputc('*', archE)
}
```

thank you!

Comment: I guess fopen inside loop is a typo! Is it fseek?

Comment: That isn't your *real* code, is it? I mean, you're using `fseek`, not `fopen`, right ? Post **real** code that reproduces your problem please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must open separate file descriptor for each thread (so each will have separate file pointer). Then you must link your program with MT C runtime. Everything should work without mutexes.

Comment: thank you so much! it works like a charm, Im giving every thread the string with the name of the file.